# Why does my compiler return a syntax error when I try to fetch a value from a dictionary the second time?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

I have a dictionary in which I have names and their relations to Luke Skywalker:

`names = {'Darth Vader' : 'Father', 'Leia' : 'Sister'}`

My code asks for a name and when you enter a name, it spits out the value from the dictionary.

```
print('Enter a name:')
name = input()
print(names[name])
```

When I run my code and I enter in "Darth Vader", it returns "Father".
But when I do it a second time, it gives me a Syntax Error.

```
Darth Vader
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    Darth Vader
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Something is wrong elsewhere. Can you provide all the code?

Comment: did you restart code ? It looks like it treats it as Python code, not text for `input()`. If you want to send many values then you should run code in some loop - to execute `input()` many times. Without loop `input()` will be executed only once and it will get only one line. And next line will be treated as new Python code.

Comment: @Frederick that is all of the code.

Comment: @furas Thanks, I put it in a "While True:" loop and was able to do it multiple times.